# Docker jetty application does not see files from volume

Tags: java, permissions, docker, jetty, volume

I have two dockerized applications and additional volume container:

- `dbdata` volume container has one volume: `/home/git/data`
- dockerized [Gitlab](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab) - runned with `--volumes-from dbdata` to mount volume from volume container,
- my own application https://github.com/tunguski/gitlab-java-event-listener - runned with `--volumes-from dbdata` to mount volume from volume container ([Dockerfile](https://github.com/tunguski/gitlab-java-event-listener/blob/master/Dockerfile)).

My application tries to clone git repository from `/home/git/data/repositories`. This directory is owned by user `git` from gitlab container. But after adding

```
RUN groupadd --gid 1000 git && usermod -a -G git jetty
```

to Dockerfile, user `jetty` sees files in it. I've tested it executing `su - jetty` and `ls -la /home/git/data/repositories`.

JGit reports that `/home/git/data/repositories/<user>/<repo.git>` does not exist. I modified app to log what parent directory actually exist, and it's `/home/git/data/repositories`. My java application does not see any subdirectories.

But when I connect to my app's container using:

```
docker exec -it my-app bash
```

change user to jetty:

```
su - jetty
```

then listing directory:

```
ls -la /home/git/data/repositories/<user>/<repo.git>
```

shows that repository exist!

To confirm that server runs on this particular user:

```
$ ps auxwf
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root        72  0.0  0.0  21920  3556 ?        Ss   13:54   0:00 bash
root        77  0.0  0.0  46432  2920 ?        S    13:54   0:00  \_ su - jetty
jetty       78  0.0  0.0   4328   700 ?        S    13:54   0:00      \_ -su
jetty       81  0.0  0.0  17488  2072 ?        R+   13:54   0:00          \_ ps auxwf
jetty        1  0.5  5.7 5627056 464960 ?      Ssl  12:56   0:18 /usr/bin/java -Djetty.logging.dir=/usr/local/jetty/logs -Djetty.home=/usr/local/jetty -Djetty.base=/var/lib/jetty -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/jett[...]
```

I really don't know what is the problem here.

Do you know what may be the cause of this?